# Is it possible to create a Sortable ul data-role="listview" in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to create a sortable UL list in asp.net mvc similar to [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/pes2d), I am able to accomplish this in HTML and jquery.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Re-order</li>
        <li data-theme="c">1</li>
        <li data-theme="c">2</li>
        <li data-theme="c">3</li>
        <li data-theme="c">4</li>
        <li data-theme="c">5</li>
        <li data-theme="c">6</li>
        <li data-theme="c">7</li>
    </ul>
    <a data-role="button">Submit</a>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
$('ul')
    .addClass('ui-corner-top')
    .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
    .sortable({
        'containment': 'parent',
        'opacity': 0.6,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
        }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing the following I was able to post the data just fine

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sendData").click(function () {
        var items = $("#sortable li");
        var tosubmit = [];
        $(items).each(function (index, e) {
            if ($(e).text() != "List") {
                var nextItem = { "id": e.id, "val": $(e).text() };
                tosubmit.push(nextItem);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/GetOrderListJSON',
            data: JSON.stringify(tosubmit),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - nothing in MVC would stop you. View pages consist of standard HTML and Javascript so return a view with the appropriate HTML and JS and it will just work.

Copy that code into a View and return it from an Action. E.g. put it in the Index.cshtml of Home and it should work.

Comment: yep, I was able to do this just fine